# How can I substract items in a list?

Tags: python

I have this list:

```
b = [3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3]
```

I have to subtract it this way:

```
3-1 = 2
3-3 = 0
4-2 = 2
3-3 = 0
```

I have this code:

```
 s = [x-y for x,y in zip(b,b[1:])]
```

But it doesn't do what I want, it does this:

```
3-1 = 2
1-3 = -2
3-3 = 0
```

and so go on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `step` parameter form `[start:stop:step]` to go 2 by 2 and do unique pairs and not double each element

- `b[::2]`  does `3 3 4 3`
- `b[1::2]` does `1 3 2 3`

```
s = [x-y for x,y in zip(b[::2],b[1::2])]
```

---

First solution creates 2 temporary lists containing each a half of the initial values, you can remove the small overhead with indexed-base solution

```
s = [b[i]-b[i+1] for i in range(0, len(b)-1, 2)]
```

Comment: The only draw back of this is that the slices create two temporary copies of (half) the list.

Answer (score 2):

Just when I thought I had a use for the new *walrus operator*, `:=`, it turns out that *comprehension iterable expression* is one of the disallowed uses.  Oh well, I'll just throw a `lambda` at the problem:

```
b = [3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3]

s = (lambda i: [a - next(i) for a in i])(iter(b))

print(s)
```

Comment: Cool, i never knew about `iter` and `next`.

Comment: Even simpler, `s = (lambda i: [x - y for x, y in zip(i, i))(iter(b))`.

Comment: Or even `s = (lambda i: list(map(sub, i, i)))(iter(b))`. In both cases, `map` and `zip` alternate calls to `next` on the same iterator, via separate references to that iterator.

Comment: I would just use two statements, though: `itr = iter(b); s = [x - y for x,y in zip(itr, itr)]`.

Comment: Or `[x - y for itr in [iter(b)] for x, y in zip(itr, itr)]`, using another contruct that `:=` was supposed to replace.

Comment: @chepner, I appreciate your alternatives but I still prefer my approach.  I was intentionally avoiding `zip()` as it already part of other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this list comprehension:

```
b = [3, 1, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3]
b = [v-b[i+1] for i,v in enumerate(b[:-1]) if not i%2]
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[2, 0, 2, 0]
```